# Sql datetime calculation

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, excel, datetime

I have an Excel sheet and have this formula below. I would like to calculate the same formula with sql. The result will be in second.

Thank you,

```
declare @t1 AS datetime
declare @t2 AS datetime
declare @t3 AS datetime
declare @t4 AS datetime

set @t1 = '2011-11-04 00:00:00.000' --start date
set @t2 = '2012-01-16 18:21:55.000' --start time
set @t3 = '2011-11-10 00:00:00.000' --end date
set @t4 = '2012-01-16 12:10:00.000' --end time
```

Excel formula

```
((end date-start date-1)+(end time-(0,375)))*24*60*60
```

0,375 value means 9 hour

formula result will be  = 443400 second

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **PLEASE** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it! (no need to end each line with a `<br>` ...)

Comment: So start time is not used in your formula?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mention that you not using Start Time in your formula?

Here it comes:

```
declare @t1 AS datetime
declare @t2 AS datetime
declare @t3 AS datetime
declare @t4 AS datetime

set @t1 = '2011-11-04 00:00:00.000' --start date
set @t2 = '2012-01-16 18:21:55.000' --start time
set @t3 = '2011-11-10 00:00:00.000' --end date
set @t4 = '2012-01-16 12:10:00.000' --end time

SELECT CAST((DATEDIFF(d, @t1, @t3)-1 + (CAST(@t4 AS FLOAT) - FLOOR(CAST(@t4 AS FLOAT)) - 0.375))*24*60*60 AS INT)
```

Comment: Thank you Oleg, do you know any web site about date calculation in sql for practicing ?

Comment: Google Sql Server Books Online